# Whats Wrong with the Stored Procedure below?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
alter procedure product_sales 
@productid int,
@quantitysell int
as 
begin
    declare @productname varchar(20)
    declare @quantityavailable int 

    select @quantityavailable=quantityav from products_trycatch 
    select @productname=productname from products_trycatch where productid=@productid
    select @productid=productid from products_trycatch

    if(not exists(select @productid from products_trycatch)
        begin
            raiserror('Product does not exist',16,1)
        end 
    else
        begin
            if (@quantitysell>@quantityavailable)
                begin 
                    print 'Stock not available'
                end 
            else 
                begin 
-------------
                update products_trycatch set quantityav=quantityav-@quantitysell
                insert into product_log values(@productid,@productname,@quantitysell)
             end
```

Please let me know where the mistake is. What i am trying to do is. one table contains stock available for a product, when i execute the SP i mentioned which product and how many quantity is being sold, The sp deducts that value from the available quantity table and updates in a new table the quantity sold.

Comment: can you tell us the error message you are getting-

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure product_sales, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'begin'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure product_sales, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure product_sales, Line 41
Incorrect syntax near 'end'.

Comment: is this the complete code of the stored procedure, because you are missing many end for begin

Comment: Yes this is the complete one. Can you tell me where i have missed the 'END' 's

Comment: @AshwathRaj use identation so it's easier to see begin/end blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking very *procedurally*, laying things out step by step, but missing parts out from several of your steps.

Don't write *several* queries to retrieve *individual* pieces of data. Think about the problem as a whole<sup>1</sup>:

```
alter procedure product_sales 
@productid int,
@quantitysell int
as 
begin
declare @rc int
update products_trycatch
set quantityav = quantityav - @quantitysell
where productid = @productid and quantityav > @quantitysell
set @rc = @@ROWCOUNT
if @rc = 1
begin
    insert into product_log
    select @productid,productname,@quantitysell
    from product_trycatch
    where productid = @productid
end
else
begin
  if not exists(select * from products_trycatch where productid = @productid)
  begin
    raiserror('Product does not exist',16,1)
  end
  else
  begin
    print 'Stock not available'
  end
end
```

Not how all of my queries target the row in `product_trycatch` with the matching `productid` column - several of yours don't which means that they're going to be assigning non-deterministic values to your variables, or updating **all** rows in `product_trycatch` and deducting the `@quantitysell` value.

---

<sup>1</sup>For bonus points we could write a single `update` with `case` and an `output` clause that would eliminate the need to perform any re-querying of the `product_trycatch` table for the product name or in the failure path, but it's probably not worth the additional complexity here. This query shows the general technique:

```
declare @products table (ID int not null, Quantity int not null, Name varchar(20) not null)
insert into @products (ID,Quantity,Name) values (1,15,'Fred')

declare @ID int
declare @Qty int
declare @RefData table (OldQuantity int not null, NewQuantity int not null,
                        Name varchar(20) not null)

select @ID = 1, @Qty = 20

update @products
set Quantity = CASE WHEN Quantity >= @Qty THEN Quantity - @Qty ELSE Quantity END
output deleted.Quantity,inserted.Quantity, inserted.Name into @RefData
where ID = @ID

select * from @RefData
```

where you can play with the `@ID` and `@Qty` values to see the various outcomes reflected in `@RefData` when the quantity requested is higher than that which is available or where the product does or doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Formatted your code and added missing words -

```
alter procedure product_sales 
@productid int,
@quantitysell int
as 
begin
    declare @productname varchar(20)
    declare @quantityavailable int 
    select @quantityavailable=quantityav from products_trycatch 
    select @productname=productname from products_trycatch where productid=@productid
    select @productid=productid from products_trycatch
    if not exists(select @productid from products_trycatch)
    begin
        raiserror('Product does not exist',16,1)
    end 
    else if (@quantitysell>@quantityavailable)
    begin 
        print 'Stock not available'
    end
    else 
    begin 
        -------------
        update products_trycatch set quantityav=quantityav-@quantitysell
        insert into product_log values(@productid,@productname,@quantitysell)
    end
end
```

Comment: It works, but when i enter a product that is not present in the products_trycatch table, the SP Executes and a no changes are made in products_trycatch table, but in product_log table under productname column a null value is inserted.. But i want the error to display as 'This product is not found'

Comment: @AshwathRaj - that's because your third `select` *overwrites* `@productid` with *some non-deterministic value* from the `products_trycatch` table. Of course a check for existence after that point always succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Formatted code

```
    alter procedure product_sales 
@productid int,
@quantitysell int
as 
begin
declare @productname varchar(20)
declare @quantityavailable int 
select @quantityavailable=quantityav from products_trycatch 
select @productname=productname from products_trycatch where productid=@productid
select @productid=productid from products_trycatch
if(not exists(select @productid from products_trycatch))
begin
raiserror('Product does not exist',16,1)
end 
else if (@quantitysell>@quantityavailable)
begin 
print 'Stock not available'
end 
else 
begin 
-------------
update products_trycatch set quantityav=quantityav-@quantitysell
insert into product_log values(@productid,@productname,@quantitysell)
end 
end
```

Comment: It works, but when i enter a product that is not present in the products_trycatch table, the SP Executes and a no changes are made in products_trycatch table, but in product_log table under productname column a null value is inserted.. But i want the error to display as 'This product is not found'

Answer (score 0):

Just Modified your Stored Proc have a look at it

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Product_sales 
(@Productid    INT, 
 @Quantitysell INT
 ) 
AS 
  BEGIN TRY 
      DECLARE @Productname VARCHAR(20) 
      DECLARE @Quantityavailable INT 

      SELECT @Quantityavailable = Quantityav 
      FROM   Products_trycatch 

      SELECT @Productname = Productname 
      FROM   Products_trycatch 
      WHERE  Productid = @Productid 

      SELECT @Productid = Productid 
      FROM   Products_trycatch 

      IF( @Productid IS NULL ) 
        BEGIN 
            RAISERROR('Product does not exist',16,1) 
        END 
      ELSE IF ( @Quantitysell > @Quantityavailable ) 
        BEGIN 
            PRINT 'Stock not available' 
        END 
      ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            DECLARE @Is_transcount INT 

            BEGIN TRANSACTION 

            SET @Is_transcount=1 

            UPDATE Products_trycatch 
            SET    Quantityav = Quantityav - @Quantitysell; 

            INSERT INTO Product_log 
            VALUES     (@Productid, 
                        @Productname, 
                        @Quantitysell) 

            COMMIT TRANSACTION 

            SET @Is_transcount=0 
        END 
  END TRY 

  BEGIN CATCH 
      IF( @@Trancount > 0 ) 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

      DECLARE @Error_message   VARCHAR(Max), 
              @Error_number    INT, 
              @Error_procedure VARCHAR(100) 

      SELECT @Error_message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
             @Error_number = ERROR_NUMBER(), 
             @Error_procedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE() 
  END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

The SP is open to a Parameter Sniffing issue.

You re-assign the value of @productid part way through your code.

From this point forward SQL will be making more assumptions about what plan to use because it no longer knows the actual value.